# Lock down Windows PC with InTune to block cmd and regedit etc

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

I am trying to use InTune to manage devices joined to Azure AD, there is no on-premise Active Directory so no access to group policy. I need to be able to completely lock down Windows 10 PC's so that the user cannot access things such as command prompt (CMD) or Regedit or anything like this that would allow them to cause any problems on the PC.

I can see in InTune where I can restrict access to the "Settings" section etc but there doesn't seem to be anything for restricting the applications mentioned above.

Imagine the PC's being in a school for example where they need to be completely restricted so that no troublesome users can mess about with them.

Does anyone know if this is possible using InTune and if so how, otherwise what are the alternatives, is there a better MDM to be using?

Answer (score 0):

Applocker is the only way I have found to do this. 
Create Custom OMA-URI
./Vendor/MSFT/AppLocker/ApplicationLaunchRestrictions/000000001/EXE/Policy
Value String
Use XML file to detail what you want to restrict.
See https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/managing-applocker-on-windows-10-via-oma-dm/ for fill details. Can do the same for CMD and regedit.

IE this example blocks Powershell and python

```
<RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
    <FilePathRule Id="e16ce5e4-67f2-4ebf-ad01-c81fc8f28cd5" Name="All Files" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-5-32-544" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="*" />
      </Conditions>
    </FilePathRule>
    <FilePathRule Id="9eb15b2e-f9c2-42d4-8692-ad1a0f6a0722" Name="All files" Description="Allows user to run files execpt powershell" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="*" />
      </Conditions>
      <Exceptions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=MICROSOFT CORPORATION, L=REDMOND, S=WASHINGTON, C=US" ProductName="MICROSOFT® WINDOWS® OPERATING SYSTEM" BinaryName="POWERSHELL.EXE">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=MICROSOFT CORPORATION, L=REDMOND, S=WASHINGTON, C=US" ProductName="MICROSOFT® WINDOWS® OPERATING SYSTEM" BinaryName="POWERSHELL_ISE.EXE">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Exceptions>
    </FilePathRule>     <!-- This is a test to block python from running -->    <FilePublisherRule Id="3d6ce594-1cc7-4870-b839-48c43a8954c0" Name="Signed by O=PYTHON SOFTWARE FOUNDATION, L=WOLFEBORO, S=NEW HAMPSHIRE, C=US" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Deny">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=PYTHON SOFTWARE FOUNDATION, L=WOLFEBORO, S=NEW HAMPSHIRE, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>   </RuleCollection>
```